# 'Search Result' windows opens during every boot in Sony Vaio S Series laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio S Series laptop running on Windows 7. Every time I turn on my system, the 'Search Result' window opens automatically at the very beginning.
[image]
As you can see from the screenshot, usually 4 or 5 'Search Result' windows opens at startup and the last window will remain with a blinking cursor. Also sometimes(not always) it cause Explorer to stop working. Everything works smooth after restarting Explorer.

For the last 2 weeks I searched everywhere for a solution including here. I have gone through more than 50 links at least. I have tried everything even restoring Windows through Vaio Care. But the problem is still there. Earlier 30+ windows were opening at startup and now only 4 or 5. This was the only change occurred after trying all the solutions found.

Please help me to solve this issue.

---

### UPDATE:

Today when I started my system, I got a message from Explorer. See the screenshot.
[image]

After performing sfc /scannow cmd gave me this message:
[image]
The CBS Log of the sfc /scannow can be viewed from the following link- http://pasted.co/78df588f

NB: Search Results window also opens when the system wakes up from a sleep.

Comment: Do they open if you boot into safe mode?

Comment: That error says Win Explorer is not responding, possible just because there are so many windows trying to be opened.

Comment: Check the 'Startup' folder, on the Start Menu -> All Programs -> Startup(near the bottom) and see if there is anything listed.  If there isn't anything listed try running sfc /scannow from an administrator command prompt.  Search Start Menu for cmd -> right click -> Run as Administrator.  This will check and repair system files.

Comment: @Linef4ult Yes. Both in Safe Mode and Clean Boot.

Comment: @Cand3r The 'Startup' folder is empty. I will run sfc /scannow and let you know the result.

Comment: If it happens in safe mode it shouldnt be a boot entry or anything in startup, means its the system itself. Probably some sort of corruption within Explorer, SFC may well find that for you.

Comment: @Linef4ult Performed sfc /scannow and I got some error. The CBS log is too large. What should I do ? Paste it here or do something else so that you can see it ?

Comment: @Cand3r Performed sfc /scannow and I got some error. The CBS log is too large. What should I do ? Paste it here or do something else so that you can see it ?

Comment: @TominJacob pastebin.com NB: I'm not great at reading them so I'll leave that to somebody else

Comment: @Linef4ult What to do there ?

Comment: @TominJacob Its just a place to dump logs/code for others to easily read. You can upload the CBS log by opening it with Notepad and copy/pasting it into pastebin, then add the link in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this dism command for your new error as well, it also recommends trying them more than once if it doesn't work the first time.

It looks like this command should get past the errors with sfc.  `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` from this link http://www.eightforums.com/performance-maintenance/23398-running-system-file-checker-sfc-cbs-log.html .  There is a command prompt screenshot that I'm hoping are the same errors as you had with sfc.

You can also try this `findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log >sfcdetails.txt` which puts the .txt file here `Windows\system32`or replace `sfcdetails.txt` with `%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt`

This link http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/371252-large-size-cbs-log-files-creating-never-before.html says to uninstall the Win 10 Prep update if you have it. Then run `sfc`.

This doesn't necessarily answer your question yet, but when sfc gives an error, we should probably listen and fix that first, then go from there.

**Edit:** Have you run sfc/scannow in safe mode?  All I could see at first glance in your CBS.log were desktop.ini files that were broken, it could be causing this issue but I kinda doubt it.  I'm still looking so I'll keep you posted.

Also, I'm assuming 'when you turn on the system' means when you login since I see Win Explorer?  I would try logging in as a different user/create a new user and see if these errors still occur as another test.

Comment: I tried to run dism many times, but am getting error 87